# Differential Equation for this question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does there exists a solution of the initial value problem,

$${\operatorname{d}^2 y}{\operatorname{d} x^2} + {\operatorname{d}^2 y}{\operatorname{d} x^2} + (\cos{x})y = 0,$$

where $y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0, y''(0) = 0, y'''(0) = 0$?

Comment: Can you apply the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem?

Comment: Yes, we can apply that

Comment: So do so... Also the fact that this differential equation is linear helps with the last part: the solution exists on any interval where the coefficients are continuous and the coefficient of the highest derivative is nonzero.

Comment: Could you explain the solution a bit? I have an exam in two days. Would be a great help.

Comment: E.g. [this web page](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/systems/systems.html) discusses the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for first order systems, and the case of linear systems.  An $n$'th order differential equation corresponds to a first order system for the $n$ variables $y, y', \ldots, y^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: And how do we get the interval on which its solution is defined?

Comment: Where are the coefficients continuous?  Where is the coefficient of the highest derivative nonzero?

Comment: The critical points (ordinary point) turn out to be x^2 - 4 = 0 , so x=+-2 are ordinary points. What now?

Comment: So the interval containing $0$ is $(-2,2)$.

Comment: We can use Lipchitz Conditions here to solve this. Can you help me do that?